# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent in Telerik Reporting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, reporting

I have deployed a Telerik Report (v9.1.15.731) on a machine, and the report itself works great. But when I try to “Export” the report, or click the "Print" icon on it, after the “Save As” window appears and I save, the file doesn't get saved.

It eventually does get saved, but once in every 10-15 tries. But it is random. And this issue occurs only in Telerik's Reporting.

I have checked the EventViewer Log and found that the following exception appeared every time this issue was faced.

"Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."

Here is the full log:

> Event code: 3005 
>   Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 12-Dec-16 11:03:18 AM 
>   Event time (UTC): 12-Dec-16 8:03:18 AM 
>   Event ID: 3d4f8afcdaba4ed5bc5786c27a4311ee 
>   Event sequence: 40 
>   Event occurrence: 1 
>   Event detail code: 0 
>   
>   Application information: 
>      Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT-7-131260033658791910 
>      Trust level: Full 
>      Application Virtual Path: / 
>      Application Path: C:\Kit\CCB-GP-Reports\ 
>      Machine name: CCBSQL 
>   
>   Process information: 
>      Process ID: 1384 
>      Process name: w3wp.exe 
>      Account name: CONSCRT\administrator 
>   
>   Exception information: 
>      Exception type: HttpException 
>      Exception message: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
>     at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary''2 headers, String key, String[] values)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__f.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware''1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware''1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   
>   
>   Request information: 
>      Request URL: http://ccbsql:1010/api/reports/clients/110315-5a11/instances/103714-54ba/documents/110316-df3e110316-3e23/resources/f6a8312b165f4639a029ba42c07f56bc/ 
>      Request path: /api/reports/clients/110315-5a11/instances/103714-54ba/documents/110316-df3e110316-3e23/resources/f6a8312b165f4639a029ba42c07f56bc/ 
>      User host address: 192.168.5.8 
>      User: admin 
>      Is authenticated: True 
>      Authentication Type: ApplicationCookie 
>      Thread account name: CONSCRT\administrator 
>   
>   Thread information: 
>      Thread ID: 13 
>      Thread account name: CONSCRT\administrator 
>      Is impersonating: False 
>      Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary''2 headers, String key, String[] values)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__f.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware''1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware''1.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>     at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   
>   
>   Custom event details:

I have been stuck on this issue for about a month now, and I would really appreciate any help, suggestions or ideas to find a fix for this. 
Thank You!

Best Regards,
veggiedude

Comment: Do you have control of this API? If so, check the code where it responds with the resource. It basically means that the response has already been sent, but you are trying to send another.

Comment: We need some more information about the context. but my guess is about PostBackControls in your Ajax panel. Its look like the common error when you try to resend your document.